# Creating an agegroup variable in SAS

Tags: sas

I need help creating this age group variable. In my data age is measured to 9 decimal places. I can decide the categories I just picked the quartiles. But I keep getting these errors...

"ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator. 
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored."

I have tried rounding and changing the le to <= but it still gives the same error... :(

```
data sta310.hw4;
   set sta310.gbcshort;
   age_cat=.;
   if age le 41.950498302 then age_cat = 1;
   if age > 41.950498302 and le 49.764538386 then age_cat=2;
   if age > 49.764538386 and le 56.696966378 then age_cat=3;
   if age > 56.696966378 then age_cat=4;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

this things are better of using proc format. You are missing your variable  name after your and  arthimetic operator. also you do not need age_cat = . in the beginning. please add your age variable after and before your arthimetic operator as shown below

```
 data sta310.hw4;
 set sta310.gbcshort;
 age_cat=.;
  if age le 41.950498302 then age_cat = 1;
  if age > 41.950498302 and age le 49.764538386 then age_cat=2;
  if age > 49.764538386 and age le 56.696966378 then age_cat=3;
   if age > 56.696966378 then age_cat=4;
 run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `and le` or `and <=` syntax is incorrect.  Such a syntax *might* be something out of COBOL.

Try this form of a [SAS Expression](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p1d61passkeqo0n1jdn023ykd0g5.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

- *value* `<` *variable* `<=` *value*

Example

```
data sta310.hw4;
   set sta310.gbcshort;
   age_cat=.;
   if age <= 41.950498302 then age_cat = 1;
   if 41.950498302 < age <= 49.764538386 then age_cat=2;
   if 49.764538386 < age <= 56.696966378 then age_cat=3;
   if 56.696966378 < age then age_cat=4;
run;
```

A similar and safer *sieve* of logic can be accomplished using a `select` statement.

```
  select;
    when (age <= 41.950498302) age_cat=1;
    when (age <= 49.764538386) age_cat=2;
    when (age <= 56.696966378) age_cat=3;
    otherwise age_cat=4; 
  end;
```

The SAS `select` is different than **C** `switch` statement in that an affirming `when` statement flows past the `select` (and does not require a `break` as is often seen in `switch/case`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in your if statements with multiple conditions. Also, because the age_cat is not a numeric variable (i.e you do not want to sum up this variable), I would put it as a character var of length 1, specifying it in an format statement upfront (best practice in SAS data management).
Finally, I would also suggest reformulating your if else construct as to make it more memory efficient:

```
data sta310.hw4;
   set sta310.gbcshort;
   format age_cat $1.; 
   if age <= 41.950498302 then age_cat = "1";
   else if 41.950498302 < age <= 49.764538386 then age_cat= "2";
   else if 49.764538386 < age <= 56.696966378 then age_cat="3";
   else age_cat="4";
run;
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Why you are attaching the `$1.` format the the new variable?  SAS already knows how to print character variables. To define the variable's type and length before using it in other statements then use a `LENGTH` or `ATTRIB` statements like `FORMAT` or assignment statements.

Comment: Yes the purpose is to lock in the length , FORMAT statement is more memory efficient than LENGTH statement from a PDV construction perspective

Comment: Whose memory?  Once you have an analysis use the wrong number of groups because somehow too short a format was attached to a character variable you will remember for a long time that attaching $xx formats is a dangerous thing.

Comment: I mean the total memory usage when build the Program Data Vector or PDV for short. LENGTH statement could also have been used of course, Regarding the situation you describe that could happen however that is not relevant to the question at hand so I do not understand why your call out, all the question states is regarding a simple class variable which I am recommending to be made a character variable as it would only occupy 1 byte vs the standard 8 bytes a normal numeric var would. Both LENGTH and FORMAT statements are correct choices for this particular problem / question

Comment: A pet peeve of mine because of the danger and the confusion it causes for novice SAS programmers that see that usage and think that the format statement is actually a way of defining the variable's length. Instead the length is being set as a side effect of the variable's first appearance being in the format statement.

Comment: I agree @Tom I upvoted your comment, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

If you're grouping with quartiles avoid the hard coding and use PROC RANK with GROUPS=4. The groups will be 0 to 3 but same idea.

```
   proc rank data=sta310.gbcshort out=sta310.hw4 groups=4;
   var age;
   rank age_cat;
   run;
```

In your current program, this line/logic is your issue:

```
if age > 41.950498302 and le 49.764538386 then age_cat=2;
```

It should be:

```
 if 41.950498302 < age <= 49.764538386 then age_cat=2;
```

You should also switch those to IF/ELSE IF rather than IF statements. You should do this because once it finds the category it stops evaluating the conditions so it's not checking each IF condition which makes it slightly faster. This isn't something you'll notice in your homework but if you ever work on larger data sets this is really important to know.

```
if age <= 41.950498302 then age_cat = 1;
else if 41.950498302 < age <= 49.764538386 then age_cat=2;
else if 49.764538386 < age <= 56.696966378 then age_cat=3;
else if 56.696966378 < age then age_cat=4;
```

Comment: Once you add the `ELSE` you can simplify the conditions. `else if  age <= 49.764538386`